# pig dynamic load on number of inputs

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig

I have scenario where pig can have multiple load function, and this load can be any number depending on the user input.

**These load functions are cassandra cql query load functions.**

Primary key of table 'pqr' in Cassandra is ((a,b,c),c);

For example if user is inputs multiple values for 'a', and i **cant have IN clause on 'a'** since it is 1st key of the partition key, other solution is to have multiple cql query in pig.

```
If 'a' input values are 'value1' and 'value2'
a1  = load 'cql://xyz/pqr?where_clause= a=value1 and b=somevalue and c=somevalue' using Cqlstorage();
a2  = load 'cql://xyz/pqr?where_clause= a=value2 and b=somevalue and c=somevalue' using Cqlstorage();
```

Here user can give any number of inputs, so have to dynamically generate number of load functions according to number of user input.

Any idea to solve this.

Comment: Pig can't do this. You'll have to write a script to generate the code you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, even i thought about this, but here my another question is how to include that part of generated pig script to my rest of the pig script. Let me say that i generate these load function lines in java code or something else where i have these lines as a string, after that how do i include this part in my pig script.

Comment: You might find the `RUN` command useful.